# Vue2: Change data inside of v-for loop

Tags: for-loop, vuejs2

I have the following loop which displays images in a gallery:

```
<a href="#" v-for="(file, index) in files" v-bind:key="file.id" @click="file.selected = !file.selected">
    <img :src="file.url" />
    <span>{{file.name}}</span>
    <i v-show="file.selected" class="fa fa-check-square"></i>
</a>
```

I would like to be able to select any image by clicking on it.
But nothing happens when I click on the image.
I did it the way I would do it in AngularJs - I modify the item within the loop.

I was expecting that:
- the view (inside of the loop) will be updated 
- the change of the item will be taken over into the data array (files)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was easy - it did not work the way I wanted, because I did not add a key "selected" to my initial data array.
In AnguarJS this would not matter - the key would just be added, but here the element is not known / watched if it does not exist from the beginning.